# Applying c++ "lower_bound" on an array of char strings

Tags: c++, string, pointers, multidimensional-array, lower-bound

I am trying the lower_bound function in C++.
Used it multiple times for 1 d datatypes.

Now, I am trying it on a `sorted array dict[5000][20]` to find strings of `size <=20`.
The string to be matched is in `str`.

```
bool recurseSerialNum(char *name,int s,int l,char (*keypad)[3],string str,char (*dict)[20],int 
dictlen)

{


    char (*idx)[20]= lower_bound(&dict[0],&dict[0]+dictlen,str.c_str());

    int tmp=idx-dict;

    if(tmp!=dictlen)
        printf("%s\n",*idx);

}
```

As per http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/?kw=lower_bound , this function is supposed to return the index of 'last'(beyond end) in case no match is found i.e. `tmp` should be equal `dictlen`.
In my case, it always returns the beginning index i.e. I get `tmp equal to 0` both   1. When passed a string that is there in the `dict` and    2. When passed a string that is not there in the `dict`.

I think the issue is in handling and passing of the pointer. The `default comparator` should be available for this case as is available in case of vector. I also tried passing an explicit one, to no avail.

I tried this comparator -

```
bool compStr(const char *a, const char *b){
    return strcmp(a,b)<0;
}
```

I know the `ALTERNATE` is to used vector ,etc, but I would like to know the issue in this one.
Searched on this over google as well as SO, but did not find anything similar.

Comment: Default comparator for pointers compares pointers. To compare strings you need own comparator `[](char* lhs, char* rhs) { return strcmp(lhs, rhs) < 0; }`.

Comment: @zch - I have added  above the comparator used by me. It doesn't work. Morever, I din't quite understand the syntax of the comparator you are referring to. Please, if you could elaborate "[](char* lhs, char* rhs) { return strcmp(lhs, rhs) < 0; }" in a working syntax.

Comment: This is C++11 syntax for anonymous functors, called [lambda expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C.2B.2B_.28since_C.2B.2B11.29). Equivalent in C++03 would be a class `struct StrCmp { bool operator()(...){...} };` and passing `StrCmp()` as `comp` argument.

Answer (score 2):

There are two misunderstandings here, I believe.

1. `std::lower_bound` does not check if an element is part of a sorted range. Instead it finds the leftmost place where an element could be inserted without breaking the ordering.
2. You're not comparing the contents of the strings but their memory addresses.

It is true that `dict` in your case is a sorted range in that the sense that the memory addresses of the inner arrays are ascending. Where in relation to this `str.c_str()` lies is, of course, undefined. In practice, `dict` is a stack object, you will often find that the memory range for the heap (where `str.c_str()` invariably lies) is below that of the stack, in which case `lower_bound` quite correctly tells you that if you wanted to insert this address into the sorted range of addresses as which you interpret `dict`, you'd have to do so at the beginning.

For a solution, since there is an `operator<(char const *, std::string const &)`, you could simply write

```
char (*idx)[20] = lower_bound(&dict[0], &dict[0] + dictlen, str);
```

...but are you perhaps really looking for `std::find`?

Comment: I understood the above. Thanks for the solution, but there should be a way of overloading the comparator to do the task of comparing the strings instead of the addresses. Please, if you could !

Comment: It should work with the comparator you edited in, if you later write `lower_bound(&dict[0], &dict[0] + dictlen, str.c_str(), compStr)`.

Comment: yes, you are right ! It works. I must have done something silly earlier. Anyway, so the takeaway lesson is "char*" would be treated as an int(the pointer storing address) unless directed by an explicit comparator. Is that it?

Comment: Not an `int`, just as a `char*`. Without a comparator, `lower_bound` uses `operator<`. `operator<` for pointers compares the addresses they point to, not the values at those addresses.